# Is there a way to preserve cookies between two separate XMLHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, xmlhttprequest

As indicated in the code snippet below, I am trying to extract a token from the response obtained from the first call made on XMLHttpRequest. I then want to send the token in the second POST call ensuring that cookies are the same. But, I am not able to figure out a way to preserve the cookies yet. Could someone share what I am missing here?

```
//First XMLHttpRequest below
xhr = new XHR();
xhr.onreadystatechange = extractLoginToken;
xhr.open( "GET", url );
```

> ```
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', "abc");
> ```

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();

function extractLoginToken() {
    var params = "token=" + this.responseText.query.token;
```

> ```
>     var cookie = xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
> ```

```
    //Second call
    xhr = new XHR();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.open( 'POST', url_1 );
```

> ```
>     xhr.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie);
> ```

```
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send( params );
}
```

Comment: In this comment I'm assuming you're using node-xmlhttprequest. In w3c specs you're not allowed to override the `Set-Cookie` header on client side. If you're using node-xmlhttprequest, there's an undocumented function called [setDisableHeaderCheck](https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/86ff70effb6dd529b34650242b9e3b1f0b8b6e86/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js#L182) which allows you to use `Set-Cookie`. There's also plugin for managing cookies: https://github.com/rse/node-xmlhttprequest-cookie

Comment: thank you @Teh! I tried still it did not work. Thinking, that there is a problem with XHR, I changed my implementation to using request module. With, that I am able to handle cookies for the most part of my code, still it's not there where I am hoping to take it!